# Edit sharepoint page items e.g. required text boxes

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to sharepoint and will need you to explain how to with steps.

I have a sharepoint server running and I'm trying to edit the way the page works.  I want to make text boxes not required so I can save without having to fill the text boxes.  But I can't figure out how to edit the code for these in sharepoint to make that change.

[image]

I tried going to that page and looking for an edit button somewhere but there's no edit page or edit html anywhere.

Comment: It looks like both columns are configured as "Required" in the SharePoint list.

Comment: Some additional info would help. Which version of SharePoint? What's the list type? Did you create the list? What was used to create the form?

Comment: It's 2019, and I didn't create these I'm just trying to edit them so they no longer require input to be saved.

Comment: Did you check the list to see if these are Required columns?

Comment: How do you do that?  I've got a list of user interface changes to make but I'm not sure how to make changes to sharepoint.